# PWA + Facebook Login Erro

Tags: pwa

Ao usar o "SocialLogin" do facebook dentro de um app PWA(instalado), a tela fica branca e não retorna nada.

Ja tentei mudar o manifest.json para display "standalone","fullscreen","ui-minimal-ui , nao funcionou

A funcao de login no facebook é a abaxio

```
function loginFacebook2() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function (response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream', redirect_uri: 'Login.php', display: 'touch'})
}
```

IMPORTANTE : no browser mobile e desktop , ele abre e fecha normalmente, nao funciona so no PWA

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui resolver.
coloquei pra abrir um popup apontando pra propria pagina quando o display fosse standalone

```
 if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
                window.open('/','Pagina','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
            } else {
                return loginFacebook();
            }
```